# How can i use npm packages on offline?

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

I'm trying to develop a Nodejs application in private network.

To install any packages, I install the package files and transfer to private network.

1. But I wonder if other package has same dependencies (but it's version is different from already installed package in node_modules), Does It cause version conflict?
2. Any other package management solution in offline :)

Comment: That would not be a great option since npm connects to the online repository ever time. What you can achieve is downloading all the packages and the library under your 'package.json' file you require for your application and configure it on the application this will make it work offline

Comment: If you are under a business network, I would suggest to set up an artifactory (https://jfrog.com/artifactory/). This allows compagnies to have some private npm / maven repository, with private npm libraries etc. That may not be the solution you need now, but just wanted to share that.

Answer (score 1):

There is a great post by Addy Osmani on this.
Refer [Offline installation of npm packages](https://addyosmani.com/blog/using-npm-offline/)

As of npm v5. There is also a *--prefer-offline* attribute you can use.

Else you can install yarn instead of npm. It supports caching by default.